# Creating a Stack with an internal array

Tags: java

For an assignment, I've been tasked with:

```
// Create a stack with the default capacity 10. The stack expands
// its internal array when the number of elements pushed() into it
// would exceed the internal capacity.
```

I understand that stacks are created with:

```
Stack<T> a = new Stack<T>();
```

How can I go about doing this?

Comment: Sounds like the requirement is to *implement* your own stack with this behavior.

Comment: As in, to make an array and treat is as a stack?

Comment: No, as in create a `Stack<T>` of your own *backed* by an array. Your stack would allow an initial capacity and it would need to grow as described in the spec.

Comment: This is what I'm trying to figure out how to do

Comment: It appears that the assignment wants you to create your own class, `MyStack<T>` for example and that class should have an array to store the data as well as `push()`, `pop()`, etc.

Comment: It would be a good exercise, then, to investigate the Java source files for `Stack` and `Vector`. You can find them in the src directory of the JDK.